# How can an electret microphone have a more or less flat response?

Tags: microphone, jfet, electret

I've got two concerns. The first is that the voltage across the electret capacitor is proportional to \$\frac{1}{d^2}\$. For the voltage to be proportional to the pressure difference between both sides of the membrane, it would mean that the membrane would have to deform in the precise manner so that it would work, which I don't see how one could make that happen.

EDIT: \$C \propto \frac{1}{d}\$ actually, and not \$\frac{1}{d^2}\$. And since \$V=\frac{Q}{C}\propto d\$, the only thing to ensure is that the membrane behave linearly, which probably is the case as long as the movement is small enough.

The second concern is this circuit: [image: Electret microphone buffer]

I really don't see why it should be linear, since \$I_d\$ is not proportional to \$V_{gs}\$.

Comment: Note that the phrase "flat response" refers to frequency response. The body of your question is actually about linearity, which is a different topic altogether.

Comment: Doesn't linearity guarantee a flat response?

Comment: No, not at all. They are completely orthogonal issues. Good linearity means low distortion, but says nothing at all about frequency response.

Comment: FET buffer is a square-law (nonlinear) device. Am guessing that its transconductance is swept over such a small range by the audio signal that it is linear enough.

Comment: It seems you are conflating t as "displacement" with t as "time".

Comment: @Jonas: Your first concern can be dismissed: \$ C \propto \frac {1}{d} \$ and not \$ \frac {1}{d^2} \$.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: I don't really understand, but I may have a poor understanding of the subject. How I see it is that linearity means that the output signal is proportional to the input signal. In that case the ratio between \$\hat{f}_\mathrm{in}(\nu)\$ and \$\hat{f}_\mathrm{out}(\nu)\$ is perfectly flat, because both Fourier transform are also proportional to each other. And the reciprocal is also true: if the frequency ratio is flat, the ouput is linearly dependent to the input. Where am I wrong?

Comment: No, the [definition of linearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_circuit) is broader than that. It does NOT mean that the instantaneous output is always directly proportional to the instantaneous input. For a linear circuit, its response to a sum of two inputs is equal to the sum of its responses to the signals individually.

Comment: Regarding distortion with JFET, do you have a patience to read the openmusic lab article to the end? It also addresses your non-linearity concern...

Comment: @Dave Tweed I still don't really understand the point. If a circuit behave like \$f_{out}=k\cdot f_{in}\$, then if you have two signals \$A\$ and \$B\$ and you sum them, you would have \$f_{in}=A_{in}+B_{in}\$ and \$f_{out}=k\cdot f_{in}=k\cdot(A_{in} + B_{in})=k\cdot A_{in}+k\cdot B_{in}\$, but since \$A_{out}=k\cdot A_{in}\$ and \$B_{out} =k\cdot B_{in}\$, you could also write \$f_{out}=A_{out}+B_{out}\$. And since \$\frac{\hat{f}_{out}}{\hat{f}_{in}}=k\Rightarrow f_{out}=k\cdot f_{in}\$, a flat frequency response imply linearity. But I think I didn't get something.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Thank you, I'll read it.

Comment: A circuit like \$f_{out}=k\cdot f_{in}\$ IS both flat and linear if \$k\$ is a constant, but linearity covers more circuits than just that. \$\frac{\hat{f}_{out}}{\hat{f}_{in}}=K(\omega)\$ -- in other words, your \$k\$ is a function of frequency. It doesn't need to have the same value for every frequency and it does NOT imply \$f_{out}=k\cdot f_{in}\$; it only implies that if \$K=\hat{k}\$, then \$f_{out}=k* f_{in}\$ -- i.e., the output of the circuit is the time-domain convolution of the input with the circuit's impulse response.

Comment: @Dave Tweed OK! Then, linearity of an amplifier (that means \$V_{out}=k\cdot V_{in}\$) is not at all the same thing as the linearity we are talking about here?

Comment: No, it IS the same thing. As I said before, \$V_{out}=k\cdot V_{in}\$ is the special case of a circuit that is both linear AND has a flat frequency response. But not all linear circuits have flat frequency responses.

Comment: @Dave Tweed We agree but we haven't the same definition of being the same thing. But I think I finally got the point, which is what matters the most. But what would be the most important thing for an audio amplifier? That \$V_\mathrm{out}=k\cdot V_\mathrm{in}\$ or that you can use the superposition principle? The first implies the second, but the second isn't really important audiowise, I think. Or is it?

Comment: Actually, it (superposition) is the key feature for audio amplifiers. Flat frequency response is rarely important -- that's why we have tone controls, equalizers, etc. The "pure gain block" (\$V_{out}=k\cdot V_{in}\$) is used only in special places where the engineer wants to be sure that the equalization done elsewhere is not being modified.

Comment: @Dave Tweed I won't ask you why because it will end up in an endless discussion. I'd better look into signal theory because I really lack a formal background to understand all the conséquences. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned with linearity of voltage response to membrane displacement, the response is linear. Instead of reconstructing the math myself, here is the explanation from [openmusiclabs.com](http://www.openmusiclabs.com/learning/sensors/electret-microphones/):

[image]

As one can see, the response is linear, which is why electret (and condenser) mikes are the best.

The "flatness" of frequency response over the range of acoustic waves is provided due to small size of membrane relative to acoustic wavelength.